# How to store multiple records via JSON from a Debugger (Lumen, RESTClient)

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I'm using RESTClient to send the http request to the backend:
restclient.net

Currently, my JSON looks like this:

```
[
{"title":"my blogADD","description":"myblogdescriptionADD","status":1},
{"title":"my blogUPDATEDADD","description":"myblogdescriptionUPDATEDADD","status":1},
{"title":"my blog33","description":"myblogdescription33ADD","status":1}
]
```

The table in the DB looks like this, its name is "articles":
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJmXQ.jpg

The function inside the controller responsible to insert the data looks like this:

```
public function create(Request $request){

  $this->validate($request, [
    'title' => 'required',
    'description' => 'required'
  ]);
  //insert record

  $article = Article::create($request->all());
  return response()->json($article, 201);

}
```

So far, when I send the request, the data doesn't get inserted.
The header is set to content-type:application/json
inserting a single record works.
Sending the above array of objects doesn't do anything, it doesn't even throw an error.

I already read somewhere that one might use the id as key to identify each object inside the array. But is that really the problem here?
The ID of the table is already the PK and its set to AUTO_INCREMENT, so at least technically assigning an ID manually shouldnt be necessary, although of course the order of the inserted might differ from the order they arrived inside the inputted array.

So what am I missing?

I am pretty new to Lumen, and I'm just learning to use the model. 
The controller code stems from a tutorial video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Oxfb_HNY0U

I must admit that I don't really understand what the

```
$request->all()
```

inside

```
  $article = Article::create($request->all());
```

does.
When reading the official laravelDOC, I found this syntax to save records to the DB

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Flight;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class FlightController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new flight instance.
     *
     * @param  Request  $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        // Validate the request...

        $flight = new Flight;

        $flight->name = $request->name;

        $flight->save();
    }
}
```

and it differs quite a lot from what I have, so I wonder how my syntax actually worx xD

EDIT:
Here is the debugging result of $request->all()

```
^ array:3 [
  0 => array:3 [
    "title" => "my blogADD"
    "description" => "myblogdescriptionADD"
    "status" => 1
  ]
  1 => array:3 [
    "title" => "my blogUPDATEDADD"
    "description" => "myblogdescriptionUPDATEDADD"
    "status" => 1
  ]
  2 => array:3 [
    "title" => "my blog33"
    "description" => "myblogdescription33ADD"
    "status" => 1
  ]
]
```

Comment: Plz debugger what `$request->all()` is

Comment: @TsaiKoga I edited in the debugging result

Answer (score 1):

See The API:

https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_create

`create` is only save a new model and return the instance.

https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_insert

Use `insert` instead of `create`

```php
Article::insert($request->all());
```